# No nodes available to query error

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, presto

I am trying to make Presto work on Cloudera VM (after failing to run it with plain Hadoop and Amazon). Basicaly I have everything (coordinator, discovery, worker) on same node.
I followed the instructions in docs and I am getting an error as below when running select queries.
I generated UUIDs to use for node ids per another post, but still the same issue.
can someone help.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No nodes available to run query
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:150) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.NodeScheduler$NodeSelector.selectNode(NodeScheduler.java:166) ~[presto-main-0.52.jar:0.52]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.chooseNode(SqlStageExecution.java:531) [presto-main-0.52.jar:0.52]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.startTasks(SqlStageExecution.java:467) [presto-main-0.52.jar:0.52]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution.access$300(SqlStageExecution.java:80) [presto-main-0.52.jar:0.52]
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlStageExecution$5.run(SqlStageExecution.java:435) [presto-main-0.52.jar:0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the configuration that is working for me on Cloudera VM 4.3.0 VirtualBox image:

etc/node.properties

```
node.environment=production
node.id=FA7BA366-0253-43CA-99DE-32DD4AC11C88
node.data-dir=/var/presto/data
```

etc/config.properties

```
coordinator=true
datasources=jmx,hive
http-server.http.port=8080
presto-metastore.db.type=h2
presto-metastore.db.filename=var/db/MetaStore
task.max-memory=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
```

etc/catalog/hive.properties

```
connector.name=hive-cdh4
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://localhost:9083
```

etc/catalog/jmx.properties

```
connector.name=jmx
```

etc/jvm.config

```
-server
-Xmx2G
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
-XX:PermSize=150M
-XX:MaxPermSize=150M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150M
-Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/presto/lib/floatingdecimal-0.1.jar
```

Cloudera VM comes with jdk 6, Presto requires jdk 7, install jdk7. Don't use rpm install, it will remove jdk6 and it may affect other services. I assume that presto is installed in /opt/presto and this directory (along with /var/presto) is owned by cloudera:cloudera. Start Presto server:

```
PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin:$PATH /opt/presto/bin/launcher run
```

Run command like client:

```
PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin:$PATH ./presto-cli-0.52-executable.jar --server localhost:8080 --catalog hive --schema default
```